# Disabling events for a specific time

Tags: java, event-handling, raspberry-pi

Below is the code from - http://pi4j.com/example/listener.html (listening to GPIO). I was wondering if there is a way to disable the event from getting fired for a specific time range.
For example say I have a motion detector and want to configure it such that once a motion is detected it turns ON a light. However if there is a motion detected again in the next 15minutes (after the light was turned ON) those events (motion) should be discarded.

```
public class ListenGPIO {

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
    final GpioPinDigitalInput myButton = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_02, PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN);

    myButton.addListener(new GpioPinListenerDigital() {
        @Override
        public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {
            System.out.println(" --> GPIO PIN STATE CHANGE: " + event.getPin() + " = " + event.getState());
        }

    });

    System.out.println(" ... complete the GPIO #02 circuit and see the listener feedback here in the console.");
    for (;;) {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
}
}
```

I tried adding Thread.sleep inside the handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent but that puts the event-thread to sleep but as soon as the thread wakes up it starts processing the events from before i.e. events are stored in some sort of queue and they are processed which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than sleeping, you could just ignore the event for an amount of time

```
    long waitUntilTime = -1L;
    public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {
        System.out.println(" --> GPIO PIN STATE CHANGE: " + event.getPin() + " = " + event.getState());
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (time >= waitUntilTime) {
          waitUntilTime = time + TIME_TO_IGNORE_EVENTS;
          processEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

Comment: how would you disable the event listener for every 15minutes after it was triggered. System.currentTimeMillis() returns the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC (epoch time for linux). The first time the event should fire and then even if the event fires the action shouldn't be taken for 15minutes since the event was fired.

Comment: For 15 minutes, in the example above, you set TIME_TO_IGNORE_EVENTS to `1000 /*ms*/ * 60 /* s */ * 15 /* 15 minutes*/`

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to handle this, 2 with a timer, one without, it also depends on the API you are using:

1) add a variable to store when the event was last fired. In case of a new event compare the times. If the 15 minutes have passed, handle the event, else ignore it

```
public class ListenGPIO {
private long lastFiredMillis = -1;

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
    final GpioPinDigitalInput myButton = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_02, PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN);

    myButton.addListener(new GpioPinListenerDigital() {
        @Override
        public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {
                if(lastFiredMillis == -1 || (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastFiredMillis) > 15 * 60 * 1000) {   
                    lastFiredMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();           
                    System.out.println(" --> GPIO PIN STATE CHANGE: " + event.getPin() + " = " + event.getState());
                }

        }
    });
}}
```

2) remove the listener and re-add it after the 15 minutes are over 
This of course will only work if your API has a method to remove the listener

3) keep the listener but ignore the events, you could set a global boolean flag to handle this.

```
public class ListenGPIO {
private boolean mHandleEvents = true;

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
    final GpioPinDigitalInput myButton = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_02, PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN);

    myButton.addListener(new GpioPinListenerDigital() {
        @Override
        public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {
            if(mHandleEvents) {
                System.out.println(" --> GPIO PIN STATE CHANGE: " + event.getPin() + " = " + event.getState());
                mHandleEvents = false; //prevent 
                Timer t = new Timer();
                t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    public void run() {
                        mHandleEvents = true
                    }
                }, 15 * 60 * 1000);
            }
        }
    });
}}
```